# Creating fork relationship between existing GitHub and GitLab repositories

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-fork

I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rafisics/My_HW-Assignment_Template) on LaTeX template which was originally created by using another [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/fportales/fphw).
Now I like to show the connection and fork relationship between them in my GitHub repository. What would be the proper way to establish and display the relation?

Comment: I don't think you *can*. Forks are specific to each hosting site. Git's own relationships/connections between repositories are temporary, for the duration of each `git push` or `git fetch` operation, and then are dropped entirely.

Comment: Anything else can I do to somehow show the relation, connection, and comparison between those two repositories now?

Comment: Documentation in README files? Seems a bit inadequate but I have no other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. What is however possible is that you add a repository mirror to GitLab (Link to docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/)). Then you fork that on GitLab.

However if you need to open a PR on GitHub to the origin repository, you need to fork the repo on GitHub anyway because GitHub doesn't support creating PRs from arbitrary repositories.